# PHP - LocalHost Database Simple Connection SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, htdocs

I do not understand why something so simple is so hard.

Now when I hit submit I get the error:

Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\DataHandling.php on line 6

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\DataHandling.php on line 6

My form works, code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gym Form</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<form action="DataHandling.php" method="post">

    <span>Gym Membership Registration</span><br><br>
    <Span>Title: </Span><input type ="text" Value =" " name ="Title" /><br>
    <Span>First Name: </Span><input type ="text" Value =" " name ="Fname" /><br>
    <Span>Last Name: </Span><input type ="text" Value =" " name ="Lname" /><br><br>
    <Span>Gender: </Span><select name ="Gender">
        <option value ="Junior">Male</option>
        <option value ="Adult">Female</option>
        <option value ="Senior">Private</option>
    </select><br>

    <Span>DOB: </Span><input type ="date" name ="DOB" /><br><br>
    <Span>MembershipExpiry: </Span> <input type ="date" name ="MemX" /><br>
    <Span>MembershipType: </Span><select name = "MemType">
        <option value ="Junior">Junior</option>
        <option value ="Adult">Adult</option>
        <option value ="Senior">Senior</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <Span>Email Address: </Span><input type ="email" name ="Email" /><br><br>

    <input type="Submit" name="submit" value ="Submit Form">
```

I then get a nice message telling me the connection to the database is confirmed, conn.php:

```
<?php


$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbName = 'gym';

try
{
    //Attempt connection passing in predefined connection variables.
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbName", $username, $password);
    echo ("Connected to Database Successfully. Welcome ".$username);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    //Use exception E to return PDO/MySQL specific error messages
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}



    </body>
</form>
</html>

?>
```

However I am having an absolutely horrible time getting the data entered from the form to the prepared database.

I have tried Sqli and now tried something else.

```
<?php


    //Prepare HTML insert statement binding parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO records (Title,Fname,Lname,Gender,DOB,MemX,MemType,Email) 
    VALUES ('$title', '$fname', '$lname', '$gender', '$dob', '$memx', '$memtype', '$email')");

        $stmt ->bindParam(':Title', $title);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':Fname', $fname);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':Lname', $lname);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':Gender', $gender);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':DOB', $dob);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':MemX', $memx);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':MemType', $memtype);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':Email', $email);

    //Attempt row insertion by executing prepared statement
    try
    {
        //Insert a row

        $title = $_POST['Title'];
        $fname = $_POST['Fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['Lname'];
        $gender = $_POST['Gender'];
        $dob = $_POST['DOB'];
        $memx = $_POST['MemX'];
        $memtype = $_POST['MemType'];
        $email = $_POST['Email'];

        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    //Close Connection
    $conn = null;

?>
```

Comment: Where is `<form method="POST" action="url">` tag?

Comment: You need to have your form like the comment above

Comment: @Fil There is, OP didn't format question properly

Comment: Remove this line `$conn = null;` A) Its not necessary. B) If it is in that position you will have no `$conn` object when you try and use it in the later code

Comment: Is `DataHandling.php` in the same directory as the original file?

Comment: Yes all the .php files are located in xampp\htdocs

Comment: Now I see a `<form>` but no closing tag for it `</form>` or a `</body>` or a `</html>` Its not difficult but you do have to pay attention to some basic requirements for thigs to function properly

Comment: @RiggsFolly you don't necesarily need a closing form tag do you? And OP try to do a `print_r($_POST)` on the array and see if the variables are coming up.

Comment: Do note filename are case sensitive on a non-windows environment. Be sure your file is named `DataHandling.php` and not e.g. `datahandling.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you. Because I didn't close the tags for some reason the form was trying to connect to a file that did not exist. It is now connecting to the correct file. I am getting error: Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\DataHandling.php on line 6

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\DataHandling.php on line 6

Comment: @Jak You do if you want things to run smoothly and as expected

Comment: @JSint See this comment above [comment 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227381/php-localhost-database-simple-connection-sql#comment61984663_37227381)

Comment: You can't put `</body>` and `</html>` tags directly within PHP tags, either echo it in PHP or put it outside of PHP tags

Comment: Yes I removed the line of code con = null. line siz is the reported problem. Datahandling.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are including conn.php on top of DataHandling.php nothing will work since you're setting

`$conn = null` at the end of conn.php.

conn.php

```
<?php

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbName = 'gym';

$conn = null;
try
{
    //Attempt connection passing in predefined connection variables.
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbName", $username, $password);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    //Use exception E to return PDO/MySQL specific error messages
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

DataHandling.php 
Your prepared statement is also wrong.

```
<?php
require_once 'conn.php';

//Prepare HTML insert statement binding parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO records (Title,Fname,Lname,Gender,DOB,MemX,MemType,Email) 
VALUES (:Title, :Fname, :Lname, :Gender, :DOB, :MemX, :MemType, :Email)");

$title = $_POST['Title'];
$fname = $_POST['Fname'];
$lname = $_POST['Lname'];
$gender = $_POST['Gender'];
$dob = $_POST['DOB'];
$memx = $_POST['MemX'];
$memtype = $_POST['MemType'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];

//Attempt row insertion by executing prepared statement
try
{
    //Insert a row
    $stmt->bindParam(':Title', $title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Fname', $fname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Lname', $lname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Gender', $gender);
    $stmt->bindParam(':DOB', $dob);
    $stmt->bindParam(':MemX', $memx);
    $stmt->bindParam(':MemType', $memtype);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Email', $email);

    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

//Close Connection
$conn = null;

?>
```

Comment: I gave this a try and thank you for the information, however I get an error saying line 6 is wrong:

Comment: @JSint Put `require_once 'conn.php';` on top of DataHandling.php. And remove `$conn = null;` at the end of conn.php

Comment: For no reason this answer makes me so happy. Must be the profile picture ;)

Comment: @Jek That's the face when reading some questions on this site :)

Comment: AHAHA Yes I agree totally @TheDrot

Comment: I get: Connected to Database Successfully. Welcome root 
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\DataHandling.php on line 7

Comment: Keeps telling me : $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO records (Title,Fname,Lname,Gender,DOB,MemX,MemType,Email)  is a problem. I even Copied and pasted from here to make sure I didnt mess up..still same issue.

Comment: @JSint Could be that `$conn` exists only inside `try` statement in conn.php. Put `$conn = null` before `try` statement.

Comment: Nice! I am getting connection confirmed and no error, HOWEVER, the data entered in the form did not update the database in phpAdmin?

Comment: @JSint Remove quotes around values in prepared statements. Look at updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have got this working now. You have been a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how PDO's prepared statements work. Here's an example :

```
$s = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column=:value');
$s->bindParam(':value', $value);
```

Please refer to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for details.